# DDD - Anemic vs. Rich Domain Models

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I have read Eric Evan's DDD book, and he (along with Fowler and others) seem to think Anemic Domain Models are an anti-pattern.

So I was just really wanting to get some insight into this problem.

Also I am really looking for some good (basic) examples of a Rich Domain Model, and the benefits over the Anemic Domain Model it provides.

Comment: @SubhashBhushan this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you write some code to solve a complicated business problem. If you have an anemic domain model, than

> there is hardly any behavior on your objects, making them little more than bags of getters and setters. [..] Instead there are a set of service objects which capture all the domain logic, carrying out all the computation and updating the model objects with the results.

A very simple example is available on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model#Example):

**Anemic**

```
class Box
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

**Non-anemic**

```
class Box
{
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public Box(int height, int width)
    {
        if (height <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(height));
        }
        if (width <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(width));
        }
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }

    public int Area()
    {
    return Height * Width;
    }
}
```

You can also take a look at [IDDD_Samples repo on GitHub](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples) with sample Bounded Contexts from the book Implementing Domain-Driven Design by Vaughn Vernon. There are many good examples there.

Hiding the internals of the object protects its integrity by preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into an invalid or inconsistent state. If your business problem is complicated and you have an anemic model, your code will quickly become unmaintainable. Adding new functionalities will give you a headache and will last longer and longer. The code will be illegible and non-testable.

Also more on anemic domain model on [Martin's Fowler site](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).